# Best Open-Source example for GAE/Cloud Endpoints Backend in Java for Cordova Mobile App

Tags: java, json, cordova, google-app-engine

I used GAE on and off during the last few years, mostly in Java, but looks like recent migration of GAE into "Google Cloud" left a lot of documentation, examples and tools in disarray.

I need to get brand new Backend server started for Cordova/PhoneGap based Mobile App. It naturally needs Authentication, both internal and with Google+, Facebook, etc and needs DB access naturally.

What is the Best example you recommend for backend code in open-source (GitHub or Google's own?) where Best Practices and Architecture/Design Patterns were followed.

Preferably backend should show/make use of:

1. Login/Authentication Session management on GAE
2. All RESTFul APIs with JSON
3. JDO or Hibernate DB interactions, with auto-schema management (on Google Cloud SQL presumably) -

Bonus points for OAuth 2.0 and Push messaging inclusion, but I know I am asking too much...

Thanks a lot!

Comment: the fact that runs on cordova shouldn't make much difference. there are many samples for regular webapps. cordova app is basically a webapp. your question is too broad to answer effectively.

Comment: Agreed, wether Cordova or web-app doesn't matter. I've seen many example apps, but most don't run due to recent App engine changes... maybe I am looking in the wrong Repo's, but even Google's own samples don't deploy out of the box for me for some reason :(

Comment: I'll rephrase question to be more specific...

Comment: I found one sample that I am exploring, not exactly it, but somewhat related: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/MobileShoppingAssistant-sample

Comment: update your question and title so you get a better audience

Comment: Not an answer really but did you see Codename One? It looks like pretty much what you are looking for. It also supports cordova but I'm guessing that the Java part and the ability to compile to JavaScript as well would be more interesting to you. Sorry if this is off topic, a bit new to SO and was just reviewing open questions to up my karma.

Comment: I thought that was mostly front end framework replacing Cordova, at least when I looked at it last. I am mostly looking for services backend code.